# How to Unlock the Not Set Keywords in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, keyword

I am getting “not set” in keyword report section of Google analytics data. May I know any method to retrieve the search terms/ keywords from the not set data?

May I know what are the factors that can result in showing the “not set” result in Google analytics?

any help

Comment: I guess your problem is with organic keywords, which are no longer transmitted with ssl encrypted Google searches. This has been discussed to death and is not exactly a programming question, so it should go to webmasters.stachexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can't Unlock it:

(not set) is a placeholder name that Analytics uses when it hasn't received any information for the dimension you have selected. Occasionally, information related to a click can be lost even if auto-tagging is enabled. As a result, you may see some (not set) entries instead of keyword, ad-content, or campaign information that could not be collected.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en

Which report exactly are you having a problem with?

---

If you mean that you want to see what users are Searching the Google website on to come to your website.   You are going to have a problem Google has stopped sending this information, they want to make things more secure for users.  http://googleblog.blogspot.dk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html

Comment: i need to check whether the which keyword visitors are coming to website

Comment: You cant unlock it in Google Analytics you can see some of it over in webmaster tools though.